# Excel 2007 cannot RefreshData from shared CSV file on network drive

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-2007

I have a simple Excel 2003 file running on WinXP that uses the
Import External Data --> Text wizard
to import a CSV file from a shared network drive.

### this works fine

I now need to do the same thing in Excel 2007 on a Windows7 box.
So i goto Data --> From Text ....and repeat the steps, which are essentially the same as Excel 2003.

At this point (when Excel 2007 is trying to open and read the contents of the CSV file), Excel is throwing a msgbox error

"Excel cannot access the file XYZ"  There are several possible reasons

-The file name or path does not exist

-The file is being used by another program

-The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook

So, i don't understand what is going on.  I can manually open the CSV file by just clicking on it in Windows Explorer.  And, my Excel 2003 files can make the VBA call  ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll  and the spreadsheet updates with the updated data in the CSV file (written by a legacy c++ process).

So, why is Excel 2007 complaining??  Many users are hitting this CSV file intermitently with Excel 2003/WinXP with no problems.  Why is Excel 2007/Win7 complaining?  Is there a way to force Excel 2007 to attempt to open/import data the CSV file in Read-Only mode via VBA?

Answer (score 0):

check out http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983314

it seems to be sharing violation and the hot fix above seems to resolve this issue
may be that's why excel 2007 does not work.

Before you install the office microsoft hotfix be sure that you have already read
the cause and effect issues of this hotfix in order to not produce any damage to your running office 2007 system.

Also have in mind that windows xp handles completely efferent the files than windows 7 and specially network files.

Comment: That hotfix doesn't cover my particular issue.  Excel 2007 is not attempting to save the CSV file.  The Import --> Text wizard is able to create the original data import connection.  But after hitting RefreshAll in VBA a few times, Excel hits a wall (probably another user or the C++ process hitting the file at the same time) and then Excel can never recover from that error.

Comment: it seems that you need to renew your old c++ process and accessing the file  in RO read-only mode.

Comment: an other way is to implement the import->data from text function of excel in your own way using a VBA macro and then you can handle those csv file in readonly mode. A button and a VBA macro reading this file and place the content in the apropriate sheet i think is your solution if you can't rewrite the old c++ process.

Comment: could you post a code snippet that opens a CSV file (say, from C:\myData\myfile.csv), and then loops over the contents and writes it to the Excel file?